# I can't set margins in cell of the UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to set margins in the UITableView's cell, but it doesn't work. I set all constraints and nothing. The Labels are always in the same place - left top corner, but in the Storyboard it looks like I want. If I set the layout of a Label to Translates Mask into Constraints is fine, but then I can't set autoresize Labels. I have already made cells using the Automatic layout, but in this case I really don't know what's going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share how your constraints are set up in IB or in code?

Comment: IB? You mean print screen?

Comment: By Interface Builder, I meant your storyboard

Comment: Done. I hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you posted I believe you're missing a trailing constraint on your `City Label` that goes from the right edge to the right edge of the content view.

I always make this last trailing constraint a "greater than or equal to" constraint to allow for the length of the content and different device widths.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried it few times and nothing. It's strange, because I  did it in another TableView in the same app and it works.